# Folder Path not Working for Background Image

Tags: html, css

I have an local folder with my index.html file in it.  It also contains a css folder containing mystyle.css and an images folder containing all of my images.  I'm trying to create a background image but it won't display.  Can anyone see why?
My css is working correctly and below is what I have in my css:

```
/*CUSTOM*/

body {
    background-image:url('..\images\red_curtain.jpg');
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\mystyle.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/php; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using forward slashes instead of back slashes in your CSS like so:

```
background-image:url('../images/red_curtain.jpg');
```